# No available Audio Device after switch from NOOBS to Raspbian Stretch

Tags: raspbian, python, noobs, pygame

my program uses Pygame to play sounds. I used Noobs before and my program worked fine in Thonny. Now, i switched to Raspbian Full Stretch and now I get the error No available Audio Device. I already added `os.environ['SDL_AUDIODRIVER'] = 'dsp'`, but nothing changed Could some help maybe ? Thanks!

```
 import pygame
 import os

 os.environ['SDL_AUDIODRIVER'] = 'dsp'
 pygame.init() screen =
 pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
 pygame.mixer.init()

 -----
```

Comment: Hey guys, it worked, but instead I tried: `os.environ['SDL_AUDIODRIVER'] = 'alsa' ` and this worked. I am so confused. I am using Raspbian Stretch. Can someone explain this?

Comment: Please make your comment an answer. This will finish your question and show others that it has a solution so they don't try to help you for nothing.